# How to connect mobile server over "ssl" ?

Tags: security, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working for a project where i am required to provide "connectivity of mobile server over ssl". I have made the project on eclipse using ibm worklight plugin. I am also using a remote server on cloubees.com.

My question is :

"How to connect the mobile server over ssl ?" I am a novice on security please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a connection from an adapter to a back-end server using SSL. SSL can be configured between Worklight Adapters and back-ends by importing the server's self signed certificate to the Worklight keystore. Use the keytool program to  complete the configuration and configure your back-end server to work with the keystore.

For the procedure see: [Configuring SSL between Worklight adapters and back-end servers by using self-signed certificates](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html)